# Vba error creating combo list with Selection property

Tags: excel, vba

Hi i have a list of different value in column "D" starting at row 4.

I created a loop for created a uniquevalues string to Selection.Validation.AddType

Loop cycle for create the string (sValoriFinal):

```
Dim nrows, x, counter As Integer
Dim sValori, sValoriFinal As String
Dim sOld, sNew As String
counter = 0
sValori = "": sValoriFinal = "": sOld = "": sNew = ""
nrows = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For x = 4 To nrows
    sNew = Range("D" & x).Value
    If x = 1 Then
        sOld = sNew
        sValori = sNew
    Else
        If sOld <> sNew Then
            sValori = sValori & ";" & sNew
            sOld = sNew
        End If
    End If
Next x
sValoriFinal = Right$(sValori, Len(sValori) - 1)
```

After this code i clear range with old value:

```
Range("D2").Select
    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateInputOnly, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator _
        :=xlBetween
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
```

And finally i create a new list slection with (i think that i would improve this part):

```
With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:=sValoriFinal
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
```

result is that i have only one string in cell : **Indice;Portfolio;ExGranite;Sistema**

but sometimes i have the needed list, so code is ok but i miss some other step

Comment: The delimiter should be a comma. Please try `sValori = sValori & "," & sNew`

Answer (score 1):

### Update Data Validation List

**Tips**

- Use `Option Explicit` at the top of each module.
- Avoid using `Select` and any flavor of `Active`.
- Use constants at the beginning of the code for values that won't change in the code but may occur several times so you can quickly find and modify them in one place if necessary.
- Use the *Long* datatype for whole numbers. There's nothing to gain by using the
  *Integer* datatype.
- When declaring variables in a single row, use e.g.:

  ```
  Dim sValori As String, sValoriFinal As String
  ```

  i.e. In the 'wrong' expression `Dim sValori, sValoriFinal As String`, `sValori` is declared as a *Variant* datatype.
- Reference the worksheet near the top of the code even if it's the active sheet (`Set ws = ActiveSheet`) so you can quickly replace it with e.g.:

  ```
  Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
  ```

  where `ThisWorkbook` is the workbook containing this code.
  Then qualify each range (`.Range`, `.Cells`, `.Rows`, `.Columns`), e.g.:

  ```
  nrows = ws.Range("D" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  ```
- After the expression `For x = 4 To nrows`, the condition `If x = 1 Then` will never be true and you'll end up with a leading separator. Maybe you meant:

  ```
  If x = 4 Then
  ```

  when you wouldn't need the line removing the leading separator or the extra variable you introduced.
- The logic of the code requires the range to be grouped (sorted). You should mention this in your code i.e. add a comment.
- To delete the data validation from a range, the following should be enough:

  ```
  With rg.DataValidation
      .Delete
  End With
  ```

  It worked on my end repeatedly but I might be wrong here since the macro-recorder uses the extra lines shown in your 2nd (clearing) code which makes no sense to me. Too lazy to look it up. Any insights are welcome.
- In VBA, you have to use the (default) comma (`,`) as the list separator with data validation, no matter your locale. The same goes for formulas (`.Formula`) but optionally, you can use your local list separator with `.FormulaLocal`. There is no such option with data validation.

**A Quick Fix**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub UpdateDataValidationListQF()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    Dim lRow As Long: lRow = ws.Range("D" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim x As Long, sOld As String, sNew As String, sValori As String
    
    ' The following logic assumes that the data in the range is grouped (sorted)
    ' i.e. e.g. `1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5`.
    For x = 4 To lRow
        sNew = ws.Range("D" & x).Value
        If x = 4 Then
            sOld = sNew
            sValori = sNew
        Else
            If sOld <> sNew Then
                sValori = sValori & "," & sNew
                sOld = sNew
            End If
        End If
    Next x
    
    With ws.Range("D2").Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
            Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=sValori
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
    
    MsgBox "Data validation list updated.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

**An Investigation**

```vb
Sub UpdateDataValidationList()
    
    ' Define constants.
    
    Const VALIDATION_RANGE As String = "D2"
    Const FIRST_DATA_CELL As String = "D4"
    
    ' You have to use a comma, no matter your locale settings.
    Const DATA_VALIDATION_LIST_DELIMITER As String = "," ' in VBA it's a comma!
    
    ' If set to 'True', it will sort the range ascending.
    ' Note that it will 'mess' with the data in the range!
    Const SORT_RANGE_ASCENDING As Boolean = False
    
    ' If set to 'True', it will build the string using concatenation
    ' since the values in the range will be unique.
    ' Note that it will 'mess' with the data in the range!
    ' Otherwise, it will use the dictionary.
    Const REMOVE_RANGE_DUPLICATES As Boolean = False
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    ' Reference the single-column range ('rg').
    
    Dim fCell As Range: Set fCell = ws.Range(FIRST_DATA_CELL)
    Dim lCell As Range:
    Set lCell = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, fCell.Column).End(xlUp)
    
    If lCell.Row < fCell.Row Then ' the last row is invalid; exit
        MsgBox "No data in column found.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    'Else ' the last row is valid; do nothing i.e. continue
    End If
    
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range(fCell, lCell)
    
    If SORT_RANGE_ASCENDING Then rg.Sort rg, xlAscending, , , , , , xlNo
    
    ' Build the data validation string ('dvStr').
    
    Dim cell As Range, rStr As String, dvStr As String, IsFirstFound As Boolean
    
    If REMOVE_RANGE_DUPLICATES Then
        
        ' Build the string using concatenation.
        
        rg.RemoveDuplicates 1, xlNo
        Set rg = ws.Range( _
            fCell, ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, fCell.Column).End(xlUp))
        For Each cell In rg.Cells
            rStr = CStr(cell.Value)
            If Len(rStr) > 0 Then
                If Not IsFirstFound Then
                    dvStr = rStr
                    IsFirstFound = True ' set a flag i.e. first string added
                Else
                    dvStr = dvStr & DATA_VALIDATION_LIST_DELIMITER & rStr
                End If
            End If
        Next cell
    
        If Not IsFirstFound Then ' the list is empty; exit
            MsgBox "No valid data found (no list).", vbCritical
            Exit Sub
        'Else ' the list is not empty; do nothing i.e. continue
        End If
    
    Else
        
        ' Build the string using a dictionary.
        ' Write the unique range values to the keys of a dictionary ('dict').
        ' Note that by using the dictionary, the range can have duplicates
        ' and its values don't have to be grouped (sorted).
        
        Dim dict As Object
        
        For Each cell In rg.Cells
            rStr = CStr(cell.Value)
            If Len(rStr) > 0 Then ' is not blank
                If Not IsFirstFound Then ' create a new dictionary object
                    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
                    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
                    IsFirstFound = True ' set a flag i.e. 'dict' was created
                'Else ' dictionary object already created; do nothing
                End If
                If Not dict.Exists(rStr) Then ' string not in the keys of 'dict'
                    dict(rStr) = Empty ' add string to a new key
                'Else ' string is already in the keys of 'dict'; do nothing
                End If
            'Else ' is blank; do nothing
            End If
        Next cell
        
        If Not IsFirstFound Then ' the dictionary object was never created; exit
            MsgBox "No valid data found (no dictionary).", vbCritical
            Exit Sub
        'Else ' the dictionary object was created; do nothing i.e. continue
        End If
        
        ' Join the keys of the dictionary into a string
        ' and store the string in a String variable ('dvStr').
        dvStr = Join(dict.keys, DATA_VALIDATION_LIST_DELIMITER)
    
    End If
    
    ' Delete previous validation and apply the new one using the string.
    
    Dim dvrg As Range: Set dvrg = ws.Range(VALIDATION_RANGE)
    Dim dv As Validation: Set dv = dvrg.Validation
    
    ' All 3 options show the Intellisense.
    With dv
    'With dvrg.Validation ' no need for 'dv'
    'With ws.Range(VALIDATION_RANGE).Validation ' no need for 'dvrg' or 'dv'
        .Delete
        .Add xlValidateList, xlValidAlertStop, xlBetween, dvStr
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
    
    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox "Data validation list updated.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**It seems now good

Change the code:

```
sValori = sValori & ";" & sNew
```

with code:

```
sValori = sValori & "," & sNew
```

and assign sub to a button